# Trying to validate my radio buttons but it's just not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, radio-button

I am an extreme newbie in terms of java script validation so I wouldn't be surprised if literally everything in my code was wrong.

I'm trying to validate my radio buttons.

I previously used this format to try and do it:

```
if (document.ExamEntry.GCSE.checked == true) {
confirm("You have selected GCSE. Is this correct?");
if (document.ExamEntry.A2.checked == true) {
confirm("You have selected GCSE. Is this correct?");
if (document.ExamEntry.A2.checked == true) {
confirm("You have selected A2. Is this correct?");
```

because I am wanting it to give a message for each radio button, but of course that didn't work. (The sumbit button worked by forwarding to the next page but the cancel button did the same thing as it wasn't given a command which I didn't know how to do) I was told the onClick command would be good, but I tried it yet failed as I wasn't too sure how to apply it.

So I attempted this: (my now new code)

```
functioncheckRadio  () {
        var level = "";
        var qualification = document.ExamEntry.Rbutton.value;
        var i;

        for (i=0; i <qualification; i++) {
            if (document.ExamEntry.qualification[i].checked) {
                    level = document.ExamEntry.Rbutton.value;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (level == "") {
            document.getElementById("Rbutton").innerHTML = "You must
            select a qualification level";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("Rbutton").innerHTML = "";
            return = true;
        }
    }
```

and this is my html:

```
  <td id="RadioGCSE">GCSE</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="Rbutton" value="GCSE" id="r1" checked = "checked" /></td>
  <tr>
  <td id="RadioAS">AS</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="Rbutton" value="AS" id="r2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <td id="RadioA2">A2</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="Rbutton" value="A2" id="r3" /></td>
  <tr>
```

My intentions are to validate each radio button.  For example:
If GCSE selected then it will come up with this message:   "You have selected GCSE. Is this correct"  with a submit box that forwards it to the next page when clicked, or a cancel button that just stops the event so that the user stays on the same page so that they can choose another option.

I apologize for the long code/amount of writing. I am an obvious newbie.

Comment: That's not all of your HTML right? If so, it's invalid. You're missing `<table></table>` tags and `<tbody></tbody>` tags.

Comment: `return = true;` is invalid syntax. I presume you meant `return true;`. Also, try changing `functioncheckRdaio` to `function checkRadio`.

Comment: @War10ck No, that's not all of my HTML. I do have the other tags mentioned, just not shown above.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage tried return true;  and function checkRadio yet no help.  thanks for the reply though ( and war1ock )

Comment: Well, you still haven't shown how or when (or even *if*) this function is called. I'm just pointing out the obvious errors. Perhaps you just need to check your code a bit more carefully.

Comment: @user3093021 why did you add a jquery tag to the question? You're using just javascript

Answer (score 0):

Each input should have one unique id.

```
<td id="RadioGCSE">GCSE</td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="Rbutton1" name="Rbutton1" value="GCSE" id="r1" checked = "checked" /></td>
  <tr>
  <td id="RadioAS">AS</td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="Rbutton2" name="Rbutton2" value="AS" id="r2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <td id="RadioA2">A2</td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="Rbutton3" name="Rbutton2" value="A2" id="r3" /></td>
  <tr>
```

also you have to validate with "getElementsByName" or better, using "getElementById"

```
if (document.getElementById('Rbutton1').checked == true) {
    confirm("You have selected GCSE. Is this correct?");
}
if (document.getElementById('Rbutton2').checked == true) {
    confirm("You have selected GCSE. Is this correct?");
}
if (document.getElementById('Rbutton3').checked == true) {
    confirm("You have selected A2. Is this correct?");
}
```

Example working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rv9uu/2/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this code. It will alert the value of the radio button you selected.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
function CheckRadio() {
     var rdio = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

     for (var i=0; i<rdio.length; i++) {
      if (rdio[i].type == 'radio' && rdio[i].checked) {
          alert("You selected " + rdio[i].value); }
     }
}
-->
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="Rbutton" value="GCSE" id="r1" />GCSE<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Rbutton" value="AS" id="r2" />AS<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Rbutton" value="A2" id="r3" />A2<br /><br />
    <input type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" onclick="javascript: CheckRadio()">
</form>
```